# Understanding symmetric tensor products

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let
$$H_n = \otimes_n H = \Big\{\sum_{i_1,\ldots, i_n} \alpha_{i_1, \ldots, i_n} \big(e_{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes e_{i_n}\big) : \sum_{i_1,\ldots, i_n} |\alpha_{i_1, \ldots, i_n}|^2<\infty \Big\}$$
denote the $n$-fold tensor product of $H$. Here $\{e_i\}$ denotes a basis element for $H_i$ and $\alpha_{i_1, \ldots, i_n} \in \mathbb{C}$. Please correct me if this definition is incorrect.

I am trying to understand a particular subset of $H_n$, namely the symmetric tensor product. This is defined as the space
$$H_n^s = \Big\{\sum_{i_1,\ldots, i_n} \alpha_{i_1, \ldots, i_n} \big(e_{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes e_{i_n}\big) \in H_n: ~\alpha_{i_1, \ldots, i_n} = \alpha_{i_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, i_{\sigma(n)}}~ \forall \sigma \in S_n,\Big\}$$
where $S_n$ is of course the permutation group of $n$ objects.

To me, this says that for every vector in $H_n^s$ if we swap the order of the coefficient's components then the result is the same coefficient we started with. However this is clearly wrong, as this would imply that the coefficients must all be the same. If anyone can provide a detailed breakdown of this definition that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think that you have a typo in your definition. The basis vectors should also have double subscripts: $\alpha_{i_1, \dots, i_n} \, (e_{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes e_{i_n})$, as you're picking an $n$-tuple of basis vectors from the (infinite) basis $(e_1, e_2, \dots)$. As you have it written, you are always picking the first $n$ basis vectors to form your tensor products.

Comment: @SammyBlack Yes you are correct that was a typo, thank you. I have edited the OP.

Comment: It doesn't imply that all the coefficients are the same, just the ones related by a permutation. To be really explicit, take $n = 2$. Then, for example, $e_1 \otimes e_2$ and $e_2 \otimes e_1$ need to have the same coefficient, but $e_1 \otimes e_1$ doesn't need to have the same coefficient as them because it's not related to them by a permutation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan That was very helpful, thank you. To follow up on your example it seems that what this definition is saying is that tensors that are the result of the tensor product of *distinct* vectors must have the same coefficient, as a set of distinct vectors $\{e_i\}$ is bijective to the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ and so it can be always permuted.

Comment: No, that's not right either. Sorry, I haven't been clear. When I say a "permutation" I mean a permutation of the *indices of the indices* as stated in your definition. What you are trying to do is to permute the *indices* and that's not what I mean. A permutation of the indices of the indices leaves the multiset of vectors in a tensor product the same. To be explicit again, an alternative way to define symmetric tensors when $n = 2$ is that they are the subspace spanned by tensors of the form $v \otimes w + w \otimes v$.

Comment: In my opinion it's much more confusing than necessary to try to write this definition down using a basis, as you can see from the fact that you need nested indices. The real definition is simple: the symmetric group $S_n$ acts on the tensor power $H^{\otimes n}$ by permuting the factors, e.g. $v \otimes w \mapsto w \otimes v$ in the $n = 2$ case. The symmetric tensors consist of precisely the tensors which are invariant under this action; that's all. We never act directly on the vectors in $H$, we are only shuffling the order we tensor them in.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm sorry what do you mean by multisets, I don't think I have come across this term before.

Comment: It just means a set but allowing repetitions. E.g. $\{ 1, 1, 2 \}$ is a multiset, the same multiset as $\{ 2, 1, 1 \}$, and not the same as $\{ 1, 2 \}$ because we keep track of the fact that there are two copies of $1$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan This is all starting to make sense now. So in essence a symmetric tensor product is one where for a given multiset index, the order in which we take the tensor product does not matter (i.e. their coefficient should all be the same). If I may, as a followup question would it be equivalent to define the symmetric tensor as fixing $\alpha_{i_1, \ldots, i_n} $ and instead permuting $e_{i_\sigma(1)} \otimes \ldots \otimes e_{i_\sigma(n)}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (small) example to get the feel of these objects:
$$
2 \, e_3 \otimes e_{17} - 5 \, e_4 \otimes e_4 
$$
is an arbitrary element of the two-fold tensor product space $H_2$. Here the multi-index $(i_1, i_2) = (3, 17)$ for the first term and $(i_1, i_2) = (4, 4)$ for the second. The coefficients are $\alpha_{3, 17} = 2$, $\alpha_{4, 4} = -5$, and $\alpha_{i_1, i_2} = 0$ for all others. **But this tensor is not symmetric.** If you swap the indices (the only non-trivial permutation of $2$ indices), you get
$$
2 \, e_{17} \otimes e_3 - 5 \, e_4 \otimes e_4 
$$
which is a different tensor.

An example of a symmetric tensor in $H_2$ would be
$$
2 \, e_3 \otimes e_{17} - 5 \, e_4 \otimes e_4 + 2 \, e_{17} \otimes e_3.
$$
You can easily see that either permutation in $S_2$ swaps the first and third terms, *but their coefficients are the same,* so the tensor is fixed.

Here's how to define the tensor spaces:
$$
H_n = H^{\otimes n} 
= \biggl\{\, \sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_n} 
\alpha_{i_1, \ldots, i_n} 
\bigl(e_{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes e_{i_n} \bigr): \;
\sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_n} \lvert \alpha_{i_1, \ldots, i_n}\rvert^2 
< \infty \bigg\}
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Sym}^n H 
= \biggl\{\, \sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_n} 
\alpha_{i_1, \ldots, i_n} 
\bigl(e_{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes e_{i_n} \bigr) \in H_n: \;
\alpha_{i_1, \ldots, i_n} 
= \alpha_{i_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, i_{\sigma(n)}} \, 
\forall \sigma \in S_n \bigg\}.
$$
Almost by definition, these tensors are invariant under any permutation $\sigma \in S_n$. All that happens when you act on the sub-indices is that the order of the sum of term is permuted.

Does this make sense?

Comment: By the way, it's common to define a *multi-index* $I = (i_1, \ldots i_n)$ and denote the collection of all such as $\mathcal{I}_n$ so that your sum is over terms of the form $\alpha_I e_I$ for all $I \in \mathcal{I}_n$. With the usual action of $S_n$ on the collection on $\mathcal{I}_n$, the symmetric tensors are characterized by the condition that $\alpha_I = \alpha_{\sigma(I)}$ for all $\sigma \in S_n$.

Comment: This example was extremely elucidating and I think I got the concept now which is no matter what order you tensor a given set of vectors, their coefficient must be the same. If this is the case, how come the definition does not fix $\alpha_{i_1, \ldots, i_n} $ and instead permute $e_{i_\sigma(1)} \otimes \ldots \otimes e_{i_\sigma(n)}$?

Answer (score 3):

The symmetric tensors are all symmetrized tensor products of vectors:
$$
  H^s_n = \left\{\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{\sigma(n)} \;:\; v_1,\dotsc,v_n \in H\right\}.
$$
It follows that each basis element of $H^s_n$ corresponds to a selection of integers $1 \leq i_1 \leq i_2 \leq \cdots \leq i_n$, and that basis element is
$$
  \sum_{\sigma\in S_n}e_{i_{\sigma(1)}}\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{i_{\sigma(n)}}.
$$
(Of course, you could normalize however you please.) This means we can write
$$
  H^s_n = \left\{\sum_{1\leq i_1\leq\cdots\leq i_n}a_{i_1,\cdots, i_n}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}e_{i_{\sigma(1)}}\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{i_{\sigma(n)}} \;:\; a_{i_1,\cdots,i_n} \in \mathbb C\right\}
$$
In terms of coordinates, this means that every $e_{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{i_n}$ for any selection of $i_1,\dots, i_n$ must have the same coefficient as $e_{i_{\sigma(1)}}\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{i_{\sigma(n)}}$ for any $\sigma \in S_n$. Hence we could also write
$$
  H^s_n = \left\{\sum_{i_1,\cdots,i_n} a_{i_1,\cdots,i_n}e_{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{i_n} \;:\; \forall\sigma\in S_n.\: a_{i_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,i_{\sigma(n)}} = a_{i_1,\cdots,i_n}\right\}.
$$
This says that if any two coefficients $a_{i_1,\cdots,i_n}$ and $a_{i'_1,\cdots,i'_n}$ draw their indices from the same *multiset*, then $a_{i_1,\cdots,i_n} = a_{i'_1,\cdots,i'_n}$; it does *not* say anything about how e.g. $a_{1,2,3}$ and $a_{1,1,3}$ are related.

Comment: Ah I see now, so informally a symmetric tensor is simply that for a given set of vectors, the order in which I take the tensor product shouldn't affect the coefficient?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you so much!